# linux/bash conditional syntax on command line

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run foo if and only if the current day of the month is less than the 7th.

So something like:

`[ (/bin/date +'%-d') -le 7 ] && foo`

Except that gives me a syntax error. The date part is coming out right, so I'm asking for the right syntax for the conditional test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ $(/bin/date +'%-d') -le 7 ] && foo
```

The `$()` syntax will execute the statement within the parenthesis and return the result, which is what you want.